# WSH Panel Mod Queue Selected Song

Tags: music, foobar2000

I'm using the default user interface and am **trying to create a button to queue the selected song**, the button is in a WSH panel mod running javascript. Is there a function to either **(a)** directly queue the selected song or **(b)** send a set of keystrokes that will queue the song (where the keyboard shortcut is defined in: Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > [context] > Add to playback queue)?

What I've found about the two methods are:

**(a)** There is a function "[queue_add_item()](http://foosion.foobar2000.org/doxygen/latest/classplaylist__manager.html#a4d24d334144792d2b04d765e59da84ad)" but I'm not sure how to pass in the selected item (inputs to this function are "metadb_handle_ptr" and "p_item")

**(b)** In Winamp I was able to send a keyboard shortcut by running a file in the directory, the XML code was:

```
System.navigateUrl(skin_dir"\scripts\ctrl_alt_q.vbs");
```

and "ctrl_alt_q.vbs" contained:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "^%q"
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the RunContextCommandWithMetadb command which has a string input that corresponds to the labels in the [context] tree as seen in preferences when setting keyboard shortcuts. All that's required is:

```
fb.RunContextCommandWithMetadb("Add to playback queue",fb.GetFocusItem())
```